# How to reposition the Custom Page Elements and Text Styles at Top or Default Showing?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, ribbon, sharepoint-on-prem

I have created the custom page Elements and Text Styles by using CSS,

**Custom Page Elements**

```
 h2.ms-rteElement-StoryHeadline{
        -ms-name: "Custom story headline";
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        color: #222222 !important;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
        margin-top:0 !important;
        -ms-element:"true";
    }
```

**Custom Text Styles**

```
.ms-rteStyle-StoryContent {
    -ms-name: "Custom story content";
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #32373b !important;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
.ms-rteStyle-StoryDateStamp {
    -ms-name: "Custom story date stamp";
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform:uppercase !important;
    color: #818181 !important;
    font-weight:700 !important;
}
.ms-rteStyle-ReadMore {
    -ms-name: "Custom story read more";
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #0640a3 !important;
    text-transform:uppercase !important;
}
.ms-rteStyle-LoadMoreBtn {
    -ms-name: "Custom load more";
    font-size:16px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#0640a3;
    padding:15px 40px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: border 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: border 0.3s ease;
    transition: border 0.3s ease;
}
```

**It's Showing Look Like Below Image**

[image]

Is this Possible to rearrange the Custom Page Elements and Text Styles Showing Default ?

Like **Custom Story Heading**(Market at red Line) at Top Position.

I tried some methods it doesn't work, could you please help me in that situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should follow the below points to rearrange the Page Element and Text Style Order**

1. You should add the Custom Stylesheet Link before Corev15.css
2. Stylesheet in custom master page Link should have 
   ms-design-css-conversion="no" - Tag to avoid sharePoint reorder the
   stylesheet

Example tag look like below

```
    <link href="Your Custom Stylesheet path" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
ms-design-css-conversion="no" />
```

---

SharePoint Automatically getting first loaded Page Element and Stylesheet based on the `-ms-name` code

Now your Custom Page Elements and Text Styles Loaded top of the format Tab

**If you want to hide the Default Page Element and Text Styles**

**For Page Element**

```
 H1.ms-rteElement-H1 { -ms-element:"false"; }
 H2.ms-rteElement-H2 { -ms-element:"false"; }
 H3.ms-rteElement-H3 { -ms-element:"false"; }
 H4.ms-rteElement-H4 { -ms-element:"false"; }
 H1.ms-rteElement-H1B { -ms-element:"false"; }
 H2.ms-rteElement-H2B{ -ms-element:"false"; }
 H3.ms-rteElement-H3B{ -ms-element:"false"; }
 H4.ms-rteElement-H4B{ -ms-element:"false";}
 P.ms-rteElement-P{-ms-element:"false";}
```

**/* Hidden Text Style */**

```
.ms-rteStyle-Normal {-ms-element:"false";}
.ms-rteStyle-Quote {-ms-element:"false"; }
.ms-rteStyle-IntenseQuote { -ms-element:"false"; }
.ms-rteStyle-Emphasis { -ms-element:"false"; }
.ms-rteStyle-IntenseEmphasis { -ms-element:"false"; }
.ms-rteStyle-References {  -ms-element:"false";}
.ms-rteStyle-IntenseReferences { -ms-element:"false"; }
.ms-rteStyle-Accent1 { -ms-element:"false"; }
.ms-rteStyle-Accent2 { -ms-element:"false";}
```

Finally, we have Modified the SharePoint 2013 Ribbon Styles.